Studying modal logic using category theory
When reading about modal logic, namely general frames and algebras, I've been seeing a lot of potential functors and/or universal properties. Like constructing an algebra with Boolean operators from a frame seems functorial, or canonical frames maybe having some universal property, etc. (not sure if any of this is true, it just seems like it might be).
Is there a book or any other material where modal logic is studied this way that you'd recommend?

This approach is prevalent in the research literature on algebraic logic nowadays, but unfortunately it has not yet made its way into standard textbooks, as far as I am aware. Nevertheless, some of these things have been known for many many years, and if you squint you can find them in good textbooks. To pick up your examples:

Starting from a Kripke frame and constructing the Boolean algebra with operators is indeed a functor. It is part of an adjunction that exists between the category of general frames and the category of Boolean algebras with normal operators. This restricts to an adjoint equivalence between so called "descriptive frames" and normal modal algebras, through an extension of Stone duality.
In light of the above, the canonical frames are quite natural: they are precisely the underlying frames of the dual descriptive general frames arising from the free algebras on X many generators. Under this perspective, the method of canonical models can be seen as nothing else than general universal algebraic completeness coupled with Kripke semantics.

My suggestions to learn more about this would be: Robert Goldblatt's "Mathematics of Modality", where he outlines this duality in great detail; Chagrov and Zacharyaschev's "Modal Logic", which also details some of these aspects in great detail (though they don't use categorical language very much); and in a slight tangent, Mai Gehrke and Sam van Gool's recent and excellent exposition on Priestley duality, which highlights many of these ideas very explicitly, and can be useful to get a flavour for the kinds of topics that appear in these sorts of treatments.

I can suggest the book "Sheaves, Games, and Model Completions - A Categorial Approach
to Nonclassical Propositional Logics" by S. Ghilardi and M. Zawadowski, Trends in Logic Volume 14, 2002, MR2041391.
